# If I already have a JLabel with an ImageIcon, If I change the ImageIcon and then pack the frame, it doesn't pack

Tags: java

Here's my code:

```
/**
 * Opens file and gives a warning if non image.
 */
private void openFile() {
    final int returnVal = myFileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        myFile = myFileChooser.getSelectedFile();
        try {
            myImage = PixelImage.load(myFile);
            myImageIcon = new ImageIcon(myImage);
            myImageLabel.setIcon(myImageIcon);

            this.pack();
            this.setMinimumSize(this.getSize());
            enableButtons();  
        } catch (final IOException exception) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
                        "The selected file did not contain an image!");
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("ERROR FILE"); //PLACEHOLDER
    }
}
```

So what I am trying to do:

1. Load a PixelImage (myImage)
2. Set ImageIcon (myImageIcon) to PixelImage (myImage)
3. Set JLabel (myImageLabel) to the ImageIcon (myImageIcon)
4. Pack the frame to properly size around image and set minimum size of frame to meet the frame's dimensions after loading image.

The four steps work properly EXCEPT when I try to load a new image.
The problem I am having is when I load a new image on top of my existing image, it erases the old image (as intended) and then when it packs the frame around the new image (say a smaller image), it is keeping the frames minimum size requirements based on the old image and not setting the minimum size (this.setMinimumSize(this.getSize())). If I load a smaller image, I want my frame to resize to meet those smaller image's height and width and not be based off the old image.

Comment: Does pack work when you load a bigger image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try something like:

```
this.setMinimumSize(null);
this.pack();
this.setMinimumSize(this.getSize());
```

So the pack() method is not restricted to the previous minimum? If null doesn't work then use a Dimension of (0, 0).

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realize pack() took minimum into consideration.

Answer (score 1):

Although there are Java classes to represent Windows, a Window is a system resource, which Java largely does not control.  (All Frames and JFrames are of course Windows.)

When you call `pack()`, the system responds to a request to resize the window, but it may not take effect immediately.  As a result, the Window’s size is not guaranteed to change by the time the call to `pack()` finishes.

This is described in the [documentation of the Window class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html):

> … the location and size of top-level windows (including `Window`s, `Frame`s, and `Dialog`s) are under the control of the desktop's window management system. Calls to `setLocation`, `setSize`, and `setBounds` are requests (not directives) which are forwarded to the window management system. Every effort will be made to honor such requests. However, in some cases the window management system may ignore such requests, or modify the requested geometry in order to place and size the `Window` in a way that more closely matches the desktop settings.
>
> Due to the asynchronous nature of native event handling, the results returned by `getBounds`, `getLocation`, `getLocationOnScreen`, and `getSize` might not reflect the actual geometry of the Window on screen until the last request has been processed. During the processing of subsequent requests these values might change accordingly while the window management system fulfills the requests.

Usually, this can be accommodated by using [invokeLater](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html#invokeLater-java.lang.Runnable-):

```
this.pack();
EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
    this.setMinimumSize(this.getSize());
    enableButtons();  
});
```